# URLs wrongly formatted when sending emails. Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, email, actionmailer, link-to

I have managed to send emails (gmail) from my Rails 3.2 application with no apparent problems. However, the urls genrated in email have the :id param wrongly positioned.

NotificationMailer

```
default :from => 'no-reply@someDomaiin.com'
def report_spam(comment)
    @comment = comment

    mail(:to => "admin@someDomaiin.com", :subject => "Inappropriate content report")
  end
```

certainEmail.html.haml

```
Reported by:
"
= link_to @comment.reports.last.user.name, users_url(@comment.reports.last.user)
"
%p

Content of the accused comment:
%br
"
= link_to @comment.body, events_url(@comment.event.id)
"
%p
```

The email at the inbox looks nice

```
Reported by: " saben "
Content of the accused comment: 
" I just created a superb event!! "
```

However, those both links urls are:

```
http://someDomaiin.heroku.com/saben/users
http://someDomaiin.heroku.com/2/events
```

And the SHOULD be:

```
http://someDomaiin.heroku.com/users/saben
http://someDomaiin.heroku.com/events/2
```

This happens with all/different mailers I got. Is there anything obvious I am missing?

Thanks in advance!

SOLUTION :

```
= link_to @comment.reports.last.user.name, user_url(:id => @comment.reports.last.user.id)
"
%p

Content of the accused comment:
%br
"
= link_to @comment.body, event_url(:id => @comment.event.id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be a routing issue, in general if you're linking to a specific resource you would need the member method `event_url(@comment.event)` rather than `events_url` which is a collection method.